# RewriteRule to redirect on different file for subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

I want to write a RewriteRule and RewriteCond, so that whenever sub domain is called different file is going to processed, with same url.

I have tried by following code, but's not working for me

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain\.test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /app/test/index.php?param=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

I have configured all other steps properly. Just every time its calling index file from www, not from mentioned folder.

Answer (score 0):

You're not capturing `$1` in your `RewriteRule`, change your code to this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!app/test/index\.php).*)$ /app/test/index.php?param=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: I have tried with instructed code, but didn't work for. Its giving me 500 error. BTW, Thanks for the quick reply, waiting for same !!!

Comment: What i want is, when anyone comes to my sub-domain site, url should be as it is, but it has to use index.php from different folder[i.e. /app/test/index.php] rather that web root's index.php file.